# On campus e-resources cannot be accessed via Google Chrome Android

Tags: connection-issues, internet, chrome-for-android

I own a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tablet(Wi-fi only model) featuring Android 4.1.2. My problem is that I cannot access and use library e-resources on campus although I have my tablets MAC address registered at the computer center in our university and connect via the wireless network available in campus. The problem is exclusive to Google Chrome, I can browse using Firefox and the already installed browser without  problems. Which setting in Chrome might have to do with this? 
I am looking forward to hearing your response and suggestions on this

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to access them? Include the *exact text* of any error messages.

Comment: @DanHulme Not an error message but I am not logged in to the campus account opposed to the case with Firefox for example. Furthermore, I am presented the off campus login page where I have to provide my university account credentials; however, providing these credentials do not provide access.

Comment: You'll probably have to get the site admin involved. Without knowing how they're detecting what network you're using, it's going to be hard to find the problem.

Comment: @DanHulme I did not get the argument but I have already consulted the library staff and they were unable to provide assistance on the matter.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the library staff to be able to help. You need the people who actually run the network.